# Reduce the size of sharepoint 2010 list formfield

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-enterprise, list-form

i am working on a custom sharepoint form (newform.aspx..is there a way to reduce the width attribute of a particular sharepoint form field[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to over ride the style with your own CSS.  Look at the rendered page and use either Firebug or IE dev toolbar to see what the style is and set a new width in your CSS.